# How to make the size of frame for the bar chart in pgfplots bigger?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have problem to include all the bars in my chart.
Can someone help me to make the all bars inside the  frame?

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm, compat=1.6}  

%opening
\title{Health Screening}
\author{Hana}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}  
[  
ybar, % ybar command displays the graph in horizontal form, while the xbar command displays the graph in vertical form.  
enlargelimits=-0.15,% these limits are used to shrink or expand the graph. The lesser the limit, the higher the graph will expand or grow. The greater the limit, the more graph will shrink.   
legend style={at={(0.4,-0.15)}, % these are the measures of the bottom row containing surplus (wheat, Tea, rice), where -0.25 is the gap between the bottom row and the graph.   
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},     
% here, north is the position of the bottom legend row. You can specify the east, west, or south direction to shift the location.   
ylabel={\#Number}, % there should be no line gap between the rows here. Otherwise, latex will show an error.  
symbolic x coords={Jan, Feb, Mac, Apr, May, Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},  
xtick=data,  
nodes near coords,  
nodes near coords align={vertical},  
]  
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 75) (Feb, 78) (Mac, 80) (Apr, 75) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)}; % these are the measures of a particular bar graph. The tick marks of the y-axis will be adjusted automatically according to the data values entered in the coordinates.  
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 70) (Feb, 63) (Mac, 68)(Apr, 80) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)};  
%\addplot coordinates {(2016, 61) (2017, 55) (2018, 59)};  
\legend{HS1, Target}  
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Zarko. It works well.

Comment: Any news? You got two answer, but no one you upvote nor accept any of them, Does they not have any worth to you? As far I see, so far you not accept any of received answer on your questions ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `enlargelimits=0.1` and set `width=0.8\linewidth`,`ybar=5pt` to give more space in the x direction.

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm, compat=1.6}  

%opening
\title{Health Screening}
\author{Hana}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}  
[
width=0.8\linewidth,
ybar=5pt, % ybar command displays the graph in horizontal form, while the xbar command displays the graph in vertical form.  
enlargelimits=-0.15,% these limits are used to shrink or expand the graph. The lesser the limit, the higher the graph will expand or grow. The greater the limit, the more graph will shrink.   
legend style={at={(0.4,-0.15)}, % these are the measures of the bottom row containing surplus (wheat, Tea, rice), where -0.25 is the gap between the bottom row and the graph.   
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},     
% here, north is the position of the bottom legend row. You can specify the east, west, or south direction to shift the location.   
ylabel={\#Number}, % there should be no line gap between the rows here. Otherwise, latex will show an error.  
symbolic x coords={Jan, Feb, Mac, Apr, May, Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},  
xtick=data,  
nodes near coords,  
nodes near coords align={vertical}, 
enlargelimits=0.1,
]  
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 75) (Feb, 78) (Mac, 80) (Apr, 75) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)}; % these are the measures of a particular bar graph. The tick marks of the y-axis will be adjusted automatically according to the data values entered in the coordinates.  
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 70) (Feb, 63) (Mac, 68)(Apr, 80) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)};  
%\addplot coordinates {(2016, 61) (2017, 55) (2018, 59)};  
\legend{HS1, Target}  
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tom, how to change the y limit? let say to 5k,10k,15k and ....

Comment: @anis You y coordinate only around 80, if you increase the y limit to 5k,10k... The bar will become really short. If I understand you correctly, you wanna the y tick label to be 5k,10k,15k?

Comment: yes Tom. let say if my y value change to 5k,10k....

Comment: @anis Could you edit the question to show what you looking for, I am not quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

- It is not clear, why you use an ancient version of `pgfplots` (1.6). Upgrade it to recent one (v 1.18).
- Increase diagram width, for example to `\linewidth`,
- Define bar width, for example `bar width=16pt`
- Definition of `legend` is faulty. If your remove it, you will get (to my opinion) nice result,
- Why you reduce enlarge limits? Change it to for example to `enlargelimits=0.06,`

Consider aforementioned, MWE with your diagram can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

%opening
\title{Health Screening}
\author{Hana}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
[
width=\linewidth, height=0.6\linewidth,
ybar, 
bar width=16pt,
%
enlargelimits=0.06,
%
ylabel={\#Number}, 
symbolic x coords={Jan, Feb, Mac, Apr, May, Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
%legend style={at={(0.4,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
]
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 75) (Feb, 78) (Mac, 80) (Apr, 75) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)}; 
\addplot coordinates {(Jan, 70) (Feb, 63) (Mac, 68)(Apr, 80) (May, 78) (Jun, 80)(Jul, 75) (Aug, 78) (Sep, 80)(Oct, 70) (Nov, 63) (Dec, 68)};
\legend{HS1, Target}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```